# How to catch "Unable to load asset: assets/images/sample_img_url.png"

Tags: flutter, error-handling, try-catch, flutter-assetimage

Is there any way to catch the "Unable to load asset: assets/images/sample_img_url.png" error in Flutter?

What I am trying to do is load an asset image by providing its path(from API). But if I do not have an image that associates with the given path, I need to load a sample image.

I've created a custom placeholder widget as follows. But's it's not working as I expected. anyone can help me with this?

```
class ImagePlaceHolder extends StatelessWidget {
  final String path;
  final double width;

  const ImagePlaceHolder({Key key, this.path, this.width}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Image finalImage;
    try{
      finalImage = Image.asset(
          path,
          width: width,
      );
    }
    catch(Exception){
      finalImage = Image.asset(
          "assets/images/app_update_logo.png",
          width: width,
      );
    }
    return finalImage;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added this path in pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: Yes. there is no issue with the image path. actually, in this cause, there is no image in the assets folder. That is why the issue arises. I need to handle this senario. If the assets do not have an image called the given name, I need to show a sample image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, finally I found a really nice way to overcome this issue. Just use an error builder.

```
Image.asset(
     "assets/images/subjects/api_given_image_name.png",
     width: 90,
     errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
           return Image.asset(
                "assets/images/your_sample_image.png",
                width: 90,
           );
     },
)
```

Comment: You have to add '?' in  StackTrace stackTrace to  StackTrace? stackTrace

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to catch that exception to achieve what you want. You can use `errorBuilder` function to return any widget of you liking.

```
      Image.asset(
        "assets/images/app_update_logo.png",
        width: width,
        errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
          return Image.asset(
            "assets/images/error_logo.png",
            width: width,
          );
        },
      );
```

Best of luck!

Comment: @SUDESH sorry i didn't saw your answer. As your answer is same so please ignore this one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the asset path in pubspec.yaml like the followings :

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
    - assets/background.png
```

To include all assets under a directory, specify the directory name with the / character at the end:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - directory/
    - directory/subdirectory/
```

Official doc :
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Answer (score 0):

I think the error should not be resolved in the runtime. So specify only existing image paths. In case you have no image in specified path you should not use it.

**BUT.** If you still want to catch the exception firstly you should understand that Image.asset works asynchronously. Exception throws later, that's why you can't catch it. Take a look at this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16592#issuecomment-427991812), hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly that the thing. When it comes to Image.network we can handle this and there are few packages as well. But in my case somehow I need to find a way to catch this. @Mol0ho Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick updated answer for null safety:

```
Image.asset(
 "assets/images/subjects/api_given_image_name.png",
 width: 90,
 errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
       return Image.asset(
            "assets/images/your_sample_image.png",
            width: 90,
       );
 },
)
```

needs the ? after StackTrace or will cryptically error.